# How to drag external files into the browser using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my project i want to drag external files with extension **".opgs"** into the browser drop zone.

How can i achieve this using angular js ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an module: `ng-file-upload` - https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload.

Install with bower `bower i ng-file-upload -S`.

Load it in your head tag:

```
<script src="/admin/assets/vendor/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
```

You hook the drop action to your dom element like this:

```
<div ngf-drop="upload($files)"></div>
```

Inject it into your app:

```
your_app = angular.module('your_app', ['ngFileUpload'], function () {
```

Then you get the file in the controller like this:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    console.log(file)

    var extension = file[0].name.match(/\.(.*)$/)[0]

    if (extension == 'opgs') {
        upload_service.upload(file[0])
    }
}
```

Works quite well.

Comment: Do i have to inject this into my module ?

Comment: I added more detail to my answer. Yes, inject it by `your_app = angular.module('your_app', ['ngFileUpload'], function () {`

Comment: yeah it worked but it is not checking whether it .opgs file or not ?

Comment: what is upload_service.upload(file[0]) ?

Comment: `upload_service.upload(file[0])` is the line when you do something with the file. Possibly upload it. What did you plan to do with the file?

Comment: Ok i got it. I want to send this file through the api. If i will send this file[0] through the api, will it update in the backend ?

Comment: Sure. Depends on the api, but file[0] will be a valid file. You can also drag multiple files, that is why file is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-file-uplaod](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) plugin

it give different directive to upload / drag-drop file

```
<div ngf-drop="upload($files)" ngf-accept="[YOUR FILE TYPES]" ngf-multiple="true"></div>
```

See the [DEMO](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) page